# Why WPF Triggers must be declared into a style (even in-line)?

Tags: wpf

I don't understand why WPF allows me to write both

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasNeverBeenSeen}" Value="true">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
  </DataTrigger>
 </Grid.Triggers>
</Grid>
```

and

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.Style>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
   <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasNeverBeenSeen}" Value="true">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
 </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

but only the second seems to work. Why is there a Triggers tag to Grid element if we must use a Style?

Thanks

Comment: The `FrameworkElement.Triggers` collection only allows for `EventTriggers`, whereas the `Style.Triggers` collection allows for any Trigger types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer to your question is because this is how it is designed by WPF team.

**`FrameworkElement.Triggers`** can only have **`EventTriggers`** although property is collection of TriggerBase. It's also clearly stated on [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Note that the collection of triggers established on an element only
>   supports EventTrigger, not property triggers (Trigger). If you require
>   property triggers, you must place these within a style or template and
>   then assign that style or template to the element either directly
>   through the Style property, or indirectly through an implicit style
>   reference.